# Date format and adding a day in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, date-format

I am trying to add a day to a date retrieved as below

```
//reading fromdatabase
Dim expenddt_ As String = rdr("Expected_End_Date").ToString

Dim dt_1 As Date = Date.Parse(expenddt_)
Dim expenddt As String = dt_1.ToShortDateString()
txtenddt.Text = expenddt
```

Suppose if `expenddt_`  the value comes as **"11/1/2012 12:00:00 AM"**, than  `dt_1` has the value **#11/1/2012#** and `expenddt` has **"11/1/2012"** so in textbox `txtenddt` the value appears as `expenddt`.

Now when i try to add a day to `dt_1` as

```
Dim test As Date = dt_1.AddDays(+1)
```

Than the value in test comes as 11/2/2012, i.e a month gets added and not the day. How can i add a day?can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is a simple example:

```
Dim today As System.DateTime
Dim answer As System.DateTime

today = System.DateTime.Now
answer = today.AddDays(36)
```

[SOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx#Y500)

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1):

Well, tahnk you guys . i parsed The date to mm//dd/yyyy format and than added a day to it. When i posted this question i was unable to parse the date to mm/dd/yyyy format. Now i did it and this question is solved.

Comment: Is this selected as the answer by mistake? I believe you meant to select one of the other answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your output format is MM/DD/YYYY, so you can try dt_1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") to see the content in the format you expected.

You can also check the Day property.